# problem with Callbacks in a node JS NPM Module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing my first npm module which acts as a api wrapper for a api. I tested everything locally and it worked, uploaded and made a documentation but then I keep getting the callback not a function error

Here is the error

```
    at Request._callback (/Users/samab/Documents/js/Onetap Cloud API/src/index.js:158:20)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/samab/Documents/js/Onetap Cloud API/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/samab/Documents/js/Onetap Cloud API/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/samab/Documents/js/Onetap Cloud API/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

and the code

```js
  _sendGetRequest(endpoint, callback) {
        console.log("GET METHOD")
        const options = {
            url: `${baseUri}/${endpoint}`,
            headers: {
              'X-Api-Id': `${this.apiId}`,
              'X-Api-Secret': `${this.apiSecret}`,
              'X-Api-Key': `${this.apiKey}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
        };
     
    
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          if (!error & response.statusCode === 200) {
            var result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body));          

            return callback(result, false);
            // callback(JSON.parse(response.body))
          }
        })
    

  }

  GetScript(script_id, callback) {
    const endpoint = `scripts/${script_id}/`
    this._sendGetRequest(endpoint,callback)
  }

and how i call it

ot.GetScript("75535"), function(response)  {
  console.log(response)
}
```

All code can be found in my repo.

https://github.com/lulacoding/Onetap-Cloud-Api

Comment: Use axios instead of the [`deprecated`](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142) `request` module

Answer (score 1):

You are providing the callback wrongly to the GetScript. Look at your syntax.
This might help

```
ot.GetScript("75535" , function(response) {
   console.log(response) 
})
```

Comment: are you kidding me